# Set default alignment for cells in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, text-alignment

I know you can set the alignment for each item using:

```
TableWidget->item(0,0)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
```

However I would like to set a default alignment for all the cells in order to do not have to set it every time I create a new item. Is it possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But you need to understand you are not modifying a property of the table widget, but a property of the table widget item. First create your own item, and set it up as you want

```
 QTableWidgetItem * protoitem = new QTableWidgetItem();
 protoitem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
 etc...
```

Then each time you want to create a new item rather than using the constructor you use

```
 QTableWidgetItem * newitem = protoitem->clone();
 tableWidget->setItem(0,0, newitem);
```

Another alternative to clone (untested) is [to set a prototype](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setItemPrototype) on your tablewidget

```
QTableWidget::setItemPrototype ( const QTableWidgetItem * item )
```

This last one can be more appropriate if you are using a Ui or if the item is editable.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there is an existing method for this, but here's two approaches that work:

---

1.) Subclass QTableWidgetItem

```
MyTableWidgetItem::MyTableWidgetItem() :
    QTableWidgetItem()
{
    setTextAlignment( Qt::AlignLeft );
}
```

However, this is probably a bit overkill for just a single setting + you might want to overload all four constructors of [QTableWidgetItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#QTableWidgetItem).

---

2.) Another approach is [using a factory instead of calling new](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/):
*Note: The linked article talks about unit testing, but there are many more advantages by doing that.*

```
QTableWidgetItem* MyTableWidgetFactory::createTableWidgetItem( const QString& text ) const
{
    QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem( text );
    item->setTextAlignment( Qt::AlignLeft );
    return item;
}
```

Then instead of

```
QTableWidgetItem* myItem = new QTableWidgetItem( "foo" );
item->setTextAlignment( Qt::AlignLeft );
```

you can do

```
QTableWidgetItem* myItem = myFactory->createTableWidgetItem( "foo" );
```

where `myFactory` is an object of `MyTableWidgetFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using delegates for [cells](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate), [rows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForRow) or [columns](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn), you'd be subclassing `QStyledItemDelegate`; it has a method [`initStyleOption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption) which can be used to set style options for all cells using your delegate.

```cpp
void MyItemDelegate::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option,
                                     const QModelIndex &index) const override {
  // call base class implementation to set things up as default
  QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);

  // override just the style options you want later
  option->displayAlignment = Qt::AlignCenter;
}
```

It's more elegant and less cumbersome unlike when working with `QTableWidgetItem`s.