# how to align text of table widget in QT

Tags: c++, qt

> In my application , im having table widget , i want to set the text alignment center for all the cells in the table. For that i tried like,

```
 QTableWidgetItem * protoitem = new QTableWidgetItem();
 protoitem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
 tableWidget->setItemPrototype(protoitem);
```

> but it not working properly, guide me,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set default alignment for cells in QT Table Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827886/set-default-alignment-for-cells-in-qt-table-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a delegate to accomplish this. Overwrite the delegates `paint` event with the following:

## QAlignmentDelegate.h

```
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class QAlignmentDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:

    explicit QAlignmentDelegate(Qt::Alignment alignment, QObject* parent = 0)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent),
    m_alignment(alignment)
    {

    }

    virtual void QAlignmentDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        QStyleOptionViewItem alignedOption(option);
        alignedOption.displayAlignment = m_alignment;
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, alignedOption, index);
    }

private:

    Qt::Alignment   m_alignment;                                                                    ///< Stores the alignment to use

};
```

Then simply assign the delegate to the view. In you `mainWindow` class (or wherever you create or use the view), the delegate can be used as follows:

## MainWindow code

```
#include "QAlignmentDelegate.h"
...


QAlignmentDelegate* myDelegate = new QAlignmentDelegate(Qt::AlignmentCenter);
QTableView* myTableView = new QTableView(this);
myTableView->setItemDelegate(myDelegate);
myTableView->setModel(...); // start using the view
```

You can specify whatever Qt::Alignment (or combination of them using OR) when you create the delegate.

Alternatively, if you wrote/control the model code, you can implement the `Qt::AlignmentRole` and return '`Qt::AlignHCenter` for data you want to be cetner-aligned.

Comment: im new to this, so not able to implement. Can you change the code using "tableWidget" , so that i can understand very well

Comment: @sivanesan I've added an example of how to create the delegate and attach it to the view.

Comment: @sivanesan ok, go ahead and update your question then

Comment: @sivanesan well that won't work. You can't arbitrarily decide not to inherit from `QStyledItemDelegate`. Use my delegate exactly as I gave it to you.

Comment: :After long struggle i got success but stylesheet is not working now

Comment: that's to be expected: the delegate takes over the paint routine for the item, and so the old style-sheet won't apply. It's a solvable problem, but you'd be better off asking it in another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837036/how-to-add-stylesheet-in-delegate-class-in-qt , use this link for create new delegate class and to use in UI